Offsetting pandas dataframe with dates
I created a custom calendar to offset a date column in my dataframe if that date is either a Saturday/Sunday or a holiday as specified in the below code snippet.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
from pandas.tseries.holiday import Holiday,\
   AbstractHolidayCalendar, nearest_workday, previous_friday

class CustomHolidayCalendar (AbstractHolidayCalendar):

    rules = [

    Holiday("Republic Day", month=1, day=26, observance=previous_friday),

    Holiday("To enable to Banks to close their yearly accounts", month=4, day=1, observance=previous_friday),

    Holiday ("Labour Day", month=5, day=1, observance=previous_friday),



    Holiday("Independence Day/Parsi New Year (Shahenshahi)", month=8, day=15, observance=previous_friday),

    Holiday("Gandhi Jayanti",month=10, day=2, observance=previous_friday),

    Holiday("Christmas", month=12, day=25, observance=previous_friday)
    ]

holidays = CustomBusinessDay(weekmask='Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri', calendar=CustomHolidayCalendar())

for holiday in holidays.holidays:
    print(holiday)


When I printed the holidays specified in the custom calendar, I could see that some of the holidays specified in my calendar like 1st May, 15th August, 2nd October, 25th December are offset automatically to the previous day for certain years
Following is the snippet of the output I am getting:
2027-01-26
2027-04-01
2027-04-14
2027-04-30
2027-08-13
2027-10-01
2027-12-24
Can somebody tell me why this is happening and how to solve it?
